# img-circle class not rounding up the image

Tags: html, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using twitter boostrap to make a circular image for user profile.I have added the img-circle class to my img tag.But it is giving me a rectangular image still.How i can solve this problem?

```
@extends('main')

@section('content')

<h1>This is show.blade.php</h1>

    @if(isset($info))
<div class='container-fluid text-center'>
  <div class='row col-md-5' style='border:1px solid black;'>
    <div class='col-md-2 col-md-offset-2'>
        {!!Html::image('uploads/cat.jpg','',array('class'=>'img-circle','style'=>'width:150px;height:150px;'))!!}
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
           <span>user id :</span><span>{{$info['info']['id']}}</span></br>
           <span>username :</span><span>{{$info['info']['username']}}</span></br>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
   @endif
@endsection
```

[image]

Comment: What is the HTML output? And can you check ur console to ensure that Bootstrap was loaded without any errors?

Comment: yah boostrap loaded because i have navbar and other things which loaded perfectly

Comment: Please provide a snippet of the actual HTML that you get as outcome. Also, if possible, provide a JSFiddle

Comment: i have uploaded another image where you can see my nav bar component loaded perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine and it looks like Bootstrap is not loaded.

Add this to a master template:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: for css i have:    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: for js i have :      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: i have uploaded a new image where you can see my navbar component loaded perfectly

Comment: Please give me output html. If you have Chrome installed, press `Ctrl+U` and update your post with HTML, generated by `{!! Html::image !}}`

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
<img src="{{url('uploads/cat.jpg')}}" class="img-circle" style="width:150px;height:150px;" />
```

Basically create the element and then just dump the proper path in the `src` attribute